# PyCuda and Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I have installed PyCuda without any difficulty but am having trouble linking it to my eclipse environment. Does anyone know how I can link pycuda and eclipse IDE? Thanks in Adanced

Comment: What do you mean by "link pycuda and eclipse IDE"?  Do you mean view the pycuda library in eclipse?

Comment: @RJRyV yes, Im trying to view my pycuda library in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetBeans 6.5 IDE its provide python support.